# Counting Zeros Under Unitary Action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, convex-polytopes, intersection-theory

Assume we have two polynomials $f_1$ and $f_2$ with Newton polytopes $A_1 , A_2 \in \mathbb{Z}^2$. Also suppose that coefficients of $f_1$ and $f_2$ are generic. Then we pick a unitary matrix $Q$ and act on $f_2$. How many common zeros $f_1$ and $Q \circ  f_2$ have on $(\mathbb{C}^{*})^{2}$ ?